# ID generation strategy supported by MySQL

Tags: hibernate

This is related to Hibernate Framework. Which ID generation strategies are supported by MySQL ?
Through hibernate documentation I came to know that it does't support "sequence" class.

I am able to successfully persist the object when I use "assigned" and "increment" classes.

But use of "identity" is resulting in an sql exception caused by "Field id (the property that maps to primary key in table) doesn't have default value". Do we have to assign some default value before using the "identity" class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four strategies.

@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)

1. AUTO   -- with auto_increment
2. IDENTITY  -- with auto_increment
3. SEQUENCE -- not supported
4. TABLE  -- with  hibernate_sequences TABLE

Tested directly with MYSQL5.2

Comment: I used mysql5 dialect and set AUTO as strategy. But hibernate create a table (hibernate5, MySQL5Dialect, MarianDB)?

Comment: @Mostafa, In older versions, Hibernate selected the GenerationType.IDENTITY for MySQL databases. But that changed in Hibernate 5. It now selects the GenerationType.TABLE which uses a database table to generate primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

To use identity strategy you have to use auto_increment, something like

> create table 'table_name' (  'id' int not null auto_increment, ......
>   ... )

That should do I guess.